# Dynamic Url by setting environment variables in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, webpack, environment-variables, angular6, angular-cli

I'm new to angular and trying to implement `Dynamic API` in it. In a nutshell, `Dynamic API` means that based on the `account` that has been logged In, my app should call that `API`.So that means if I have logged in from **`Dev`** account **(rajat-dev@xyz.com)** it should call `Dev API` and if I'm logged In from **`PROD`** account (rajat-prod@xyz.com), it should call `Prod API`.After researching much, I have found out that you cannot use **webpack** in the newer ***ANGULAR CLI***. But I can edit `environment.ts`.
I have API's as 
 **https://admin-console.api.prod.xyz.io (prod)** and **https://admin-console.api.xyz.io (dev)** respectively.
How can I achieve that using from the environment variables?.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can implement your dynamic API without using the environment variables.
You just have to add an property to the account object so that you know which the current logged in account is *type* **dev** or **prod**. After that, you just make a condition on that property and match with your APIs.